# Jersey A message body reader for Java class was not found for content-type: format=xml; version=2

Tags: http, header, jersey

I am accessing a rest service that returns the following content-type header:
content-type: application/vnd.company.endpoint; version=2; format=xml

And Jersey Client throwd the following exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class com.beans.Product, 
and MIME media type application/vnd.company.endpoint; format=xml; version=2
```

was not found.

I know is related to the header format:
application/vnd.company.endpoint; format=xml; version=2 
To which Jersey cannot handle.

How can I tell Jersey to use the default XML message body reader for that header?

Comment: Try to register a `MessageBodyReader<T>` like:  
`Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .register(YourMessageBodyReader.class).build();` [example - MessageBodyReader registered on a JAX-RS client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#mbw.ex.client.mbr.reg)

Comment: And what YourMessageBodyReader.class would be?I know that Jersey by default has a processor for XML. So how can I reuse that one?

Comment: [look here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html) for some implementations. As I'm not able to know which one you use currently, its your chore to find out. There are a lot of Readers and Writers out there. But also note: You have to import them to your project, to use them. Hope this helps ...